# Filtering table between 2 dates Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am attempting to filter a table in excel using VBA. I feel like I'm pretty close but for some reason its not displaying any data after it gets filtered.  Here is a sample of what I am currently trying:

```
Dim Fiscal1 As Variant, Fiscal2 As Variant

Fiscal1 = ws2.Range("v13")
Fiscal2 = ws2.Range("W13")

x = MonthBox.ListIndex

Select Case x
    Case Is = 0
        ws.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3
.
.
.
 Case Is = 12
     ws.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">= Fiscal1", Operator:= _
     xlAnd, Criteria2:="<= Fiscal2"
```

The values in the range cells are dates (11/25/2019 and 12/31/2019 respectively) and they are formatted as dates as well.

Comment: Variables `Fiscal1` and `Fiscal2` should not be inside quotes.

Comment: `Case Is = 12`? Do you mean `Case 0`, `Case 12`?  Also `Criteria1:=">= Fiscal1"` should just be `Criteria1:=">=" & Fiscal1` (same for `Fidscal2`'s criteria)

Comment: @BruceWayne while very off-putting and weird-looking, `Case Is = {literal}` is actually valid. I never understood the appeal of it over `Case {literal}`, but presumably it stems from the VBE "autocorrecting" `Case = 0` to `Case Is = 0`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - That is indeed very weird, but good to know!  (I would bet [RubberDuck](https://rubberduckvba.com/) picks up the `Case Is = ...` and suggests just `Case = `?  :D   )